# How to size a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, decoupling-capacitor, electrolytic-capacitor

I want to design a PCB with some ICs and I've read that it's recommended to use decoupling capacitors to filter out voltage spikes. There are three ICs on the PCB: Arduino NANO, nRF24l01 module and MPU6050 accelerometer and gyroscope. So I think that I should use one ceramic 0.1 uF in parallel with bigger electrolytic capacitor for every of these ICs. Please correct me if I'm wrong. The problem is that I don't know how to figure out the right sizes of the electrolytic capacitors.
I found these equations online:

C=I_total×(dt/dV)
and
C=Imax∗tduration0.1∗Vs

but I'm not really sure whether I should use one of them or whther there is some other way to size the capacitor.

Comment: Read the data sheets - they have values and recommendations listed. THAT is why data sheets are produced.

Comment: Why are you mentioning equations without mentioning **which** capacitor needs to be sized and what that capacitor's function is? Also explain **why** it needs to be "sized", or better: given a different value. Engineering isn't about knowing the equations, it is about **understanding what you're doing** and **maybe** you might need an equation to do a calculation. When you understand what you're doing, it becomes **obvious** if an equation is needed and which one you need.

Comment: First question: What is this capacitor supposed to do? Why is there a capacitor at all?

Comment: You need to provide details on the application and your thoughts.

Answer (score -1):

Some capacitor application will benefit from a small dampening resistor included in the VDD path. A value between 1 ohm and 10 ohms is often useful, and causes only a small reduction in the VDD at the IC.

A Q of 1 results in Rdampen == sqrt (L / C), where L may be wiring inductance at 1nanoHennry/millimeter thru air, or some lower value (1/4 nanoHenry / millimeter) as a PCB trace over GND or VDD plane.

Comment: What if the "sizing" refers to the capacitor in an antenna matching network? We have no clue what capacitor needs to be changed.